# Pipelines to two commands at once

Tags: bash

Using pipes for two commands at once

Can I touch a file and and chmod u+x it on its creation? Something like

```
Touch | chmod u+x hello_world?
```

Hope you get what I mean. Still new to this so please bare with my expressions

Comment: `touch newfile.txt && chmod u+x newfile.txt` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/what-is-the-purpose-of-in-a-shell-command

Comment: The precise meaning of your question has answers here: [single-command-to-create-a-file-and-set-its-permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342371/single-command-to-create-a-file-and-set-its-permission)

The imprecise meaning (which seems to be what you want, that is, just a "one-liner") - see my previous comment, but it is not guaranteed - it is really two operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single command to create a file and set its permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342371/single-command-to-create-a-file-and-set-its-permission)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Touch and Chmod are 2 different commands in bash, if you wish to create a file with different permissions, you can do so by first creating the file, and then changing its permissions.

You can achieve this by running this next command:

```bash
touch hello_world && chmod u+x hello_world
```

Edit: As commented by another user the better approach is to use && to ensure the first command takes place before the second command.

Here's a short explanation

`&&` and `||` are boolean operators when executing `&&` you ensure that both operations succeed, with `||` either of them must succeed.

Comment: doesn't work for me if the file doesn't exist when you run this code (i.e., first time)

Comment: Yes thanks. I finally did it with touch hw | chmod u+x hw. But then what’s the difference between | and &&?

Comment: When you use && between two commands, the second command (command2) is executed only if the first command (command1) succeeds or exits with a status code 0. In other words, command2 is performed if and only if command1 is successful.

When you use || between two commands, the second command (command2) is executed only if the first command (command1) fails or exits with a status code other than 0. In other words, command2 is executed if command1 fails.

Also the single | operator passes the output of a command and gives it as parameters to the next command.